# Custom function doesn't take all the items of my dictionary

Tags: python, function

I am making code in python and I've come across an issue.
I made a function that scans a folder and gets me its last modified date and hour in comparison with today's date and time and stores it in a text file. The function works great.
I have found out that to call it for multiple folders I had to make a dictionary with the list of folders and the output name of each text file.

My problem is that when I run it, it only works for 1 "item" out of the 3.

Here's my code :

```
    import os, glob, time, datetime


def my_function(output_name, input_dir):
    with open(output_name, "w+") as f:
        os.chdir(input_dir)
        for fichiers in glob.glob("*"):
            today = datetime.datetime.today()
            modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichiers))
            duration = today - modified_date
            if duration.days < 5:
                f.write(f"{fichiers} = {duration} \n")

arguments = {"output1.txt" : "input_dir1/", "output2.txt" : "input_dir2/", "output3.txt" : "input_dir3/"}
for output_name, input_dir in arguments.items():
    my_function(output_name, input_dir)
```

In this case I should have 3 text files each named output 1, 2 and 3 with info from each input_dir except I only get output1.txt with the info from input_dir1.

Thank you for your help

Comment: why do you have \ in arguments?

Comment: because the files I need are in subfolders for exemple one of my paths is "//XX.XX.XX.XX/c$\Qlikview_Tropal\Apps\Ventes"

Comment: r u using an IDE? because there is some syntax error in the line:

arguments = {"output1.txt" : "input_dir1\", "output2.txt" : "input_dir2\", "output3.txt" : "input_dir3\"}

Comment: remove the \ and it should work as expected.

Comment: I have inverted them but it still only produces 1 file instead of 3 :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is just me being stupid. I am using visual studio code and I thought because it didn't listed the newly created file it wasn't working. Except it was and it just wan't listing it properly :/

Answer (score 1):

Note that you call `os.chdir()` without returning to your previous directory, which is why it only works for the first run, a better approach would be to pass the directory as a argument to `glob.glob()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob.

If however you're set on the `os.chdir()` approach, make sure to call `os.getcwd()` to return there later.

Comment: Okay I don't think I understand what you meant or how to do it, I will look at your link.

Comment: Your function changes the working directory, meaning if at first you were in `/tmp`, after the first call, you're in '/tmp/input_dir1', which works.
On the second call you try to go to '/tmp/input_dir1/input_dir2', which does not exist.
Because the `os.chdir()` is "cumulative", you don't return to the previous place.